# JPQL WHERE "containsAll"

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have some trouble with query, I want to get class A that have only those B that have C with given id. But if A also have another B.C it also is loading. How to enforce load with given ids if exist?.

```
class A {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<B> bList;
    ...
}

class B {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "aid", nullable = false)
private A a;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "cid", nullable = false)
private C c;
...
}
```

I try like this, but it doesn't work:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a from A a inner join a.b b where b.c.id in :#{#param.cIdSet} GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b) = :size")
List<A> findByCustom(@Param("param") AParam aSearchParam);
```

Now I do like this, but it load amount of no needed entities:

```
...
      List<B> bList = bRepository.findByCustomQuery(aSearchParam);

    Set<A> aSet = bList.stream()
            .map(B::getA)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            ......
    return aSet.stream()
            .filter(it -> bList.containsAll(it.bList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: because it is invalid JPQL, as any JPQL reference or the JPA spec would say. Clearly posting the error message would make that post meaningful ...

Comment: You seem to have received an answer below Dmitry, was it of any help?

Comment: Yes, but I don't check it, cause it not actually need now. I'll accept as answer. Thx

Comment: OK. Please always reply to volunteers here, even if you no longer need the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a simpler alternative, but this should work:

```
select a from A a where :sizeOfCSet = 
    (select count(distinct b.id) from B b where b.a = :a
     and b.c.id in :cIds)
```